# Tables html css

Tags: html, css

I have

```
    <td id="Id1">Text</td>
    <td id="Id2"><input type="text" value="Text" /></td>
```

I want that style of 2 td will be same like td1.
I tried style="border:none;", but i had text area editing or else. I just want from td2 value, but it doesn't correspond in design.
With td2 I have table cell, it can be edited. I want to have constant text showed to user, I want it not to be changed

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you clarify your question little bit?

Comment: With td2 I have table cell, it can be edited. Iwnt to have constant text showed to user, I want it not to be changed.

Comment: Are you asking for the `readonly` attribute of the input? Like `<input type="text" value="Text" readonly />` ?